# Is it safe update to latest kotlin version while using Compose in a project?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have read about some people having compiler problems when they update to the latest version of Kotlin while using Jetpack Compose in a project. I currently learning Compose and Android Studio is offerring me to update to Kotlin 1.7.0, but I´m not sure that if I do, it will still working.

I'm using AS Chipmunk and a regular Compose project (not the material 3 one).

Comment: You can check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) the compatibility between Compose and Kotlin versions. As long as you stick to that you should be fine (well, unless they release something buggy).

Comment: I recommend you working with stable version 1.1.1 with supported  kotlin version like 1.6.0, because if you work with alph and beta version, it will be problem when you release your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, refer to this table to know what version of compose is compatible with which of Kotlin:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

last version stable is 1.2.0

in the documentation said use compiler compose 1.2.0 with kotlin 1.7.0

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#version_12_2

Support for Kotlin 1.7.0

> composeOptions {
> kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0"
> }